# External id as domain identity

Tags: domain-driven-design

Our application sends/receives a lot of data to/from a third party we work with.
Our domain model is mainly populated with that data.

The 'problem' we're having is identifying a 'good' candidate as **domain identity** for the aggregate.

It seems like we have 3 options:

1. **Generate** a domain identity (`UUID` or `DB-sequence`...);
2. **Use the External-ID as domain identity** that comes along with all data from the external source.
3. **Use an internal domain identity AND External-ID as a separate id** that 'might' be used for retrieval operations; the internal id is always leading

About the External-ID:

- It is 100% guaranteed the ID will **never change**
- The ID is always **managed** by the **external** source
- **Other domains** in our system **might use the external-id** for retrieval operations

Especially the last point above convinced us that the external-id is not an infrastructural concern but really belongs to the domain.

Which option should we choose?

** **UPDATE** **

Maybe I was not clear about the term '3th party'.
Actually, the external source is our client who is active in the Car industry.
 Our application uses client's master data to complete several 'things'. We have several Bounded Contexts (BC) like *'Client management'*, *'Survey'*, *'Appointment'*, 
*'Maintenance'* etc. 
Our client sends us 'Tasks' that describe *something* needs te be done.
That 'something' might be:

- 'let client X complete survey Y'
- 'schedule/cancel appointment for client X'
- 'car X for client Y is scheduled for maintenance at position XYZ'

Those 'Tasks' always have a 'task-id' that is guaranteed to be unique.
We store all incoming 'Tasks' in our database (active record style). Every possible action on a task maps with a domain event. (Multiple BCs might be interested in the same task)

Every BC contains one or more aggregates which distribute some domain events to other BCs. For instance, when an appointment is canceled a domain event is triggered, maintenance listens to that event to get some things done.

However, our client expects some message after every action that is related to a Task. Therefore we always need to use the 'task-id'.

To summarize things:

- Tasks have a task-id
- Tasks might be related to multiple BCs
- Every BC sends some 'result message' to the client with the related task-id
- Task-ids are distributed by domain events
- We keep every (internally) persisted task up-to-date

Hopefully, I was clear enough about the use of the external-id (= task-id) and our different BCs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My gut feeling would be to manage your own identity and not rely on a third party service for this, so option 3 above. Difficult to say without context though. What is the 3rd party system? What is your domain?

Would you ever switch the 3rd party service?

You say other parts of your domain might use the external id for querying - what are they querying? Your internal systems or the 3rd party service?

[Update]

Based on the new information it sounds like a correlationId. I'd store it alongside the other information relevant to the aggregates.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, I would veto using a DB-sequence number as a identifier; the domain model should be independent of the choice of persistence; the domain model writes the identifier to the database, rather than the other way around (if the DB wants to be tracking a sequence number for its own purposes, that's fine).

I'm reluctant to use the external identifier, although it can make sense in some circumstances.  A given entity, like "Customer" might have representations in a number of different bounded contexts - it might make sense to use the same identifier for all of them.

My default: I would reach for a [name based uuid](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122#section-4.3), using the external ID as part of the seed, which gives a simple mapping from external to internal.